# « Reprends sur toi » en langage familier du Québec : emploi particulier de la préposition pour orienter le sens ?

Tags: prépositions, oral, québec, registre-familier, impératif

> Hey  chose,  y’a  3  tirs  que  t’as  pas bloqué,  gros  agrès. 
>   **Reprends  sur  toi**, montre-nous  que  t’as  des  couilles. Ce qu’on veut c’est des jeux blancs. Rien de moins. [...] ([source](http://www.agetaac.ulaval.ca/fileadmin/fichiers/fichiersAGETAAC/pdf/Agral/Decembre_2010.pdf))

On trouve *parfois* cette locution avec le verbe [*reprendre*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/reprendre) au Québec dans un registre bien familier surtout à l'oral, je dirais exclusivement à l'impératif présent au singulier ; ici on interpelle un gardien de but dans une chronique sur le hockey. Difficile d'y voir un calque de l'anglais vu que ni *get (a)hold of yourself*, *get a grip* ou *pull yourself together* n'emploie cette préposition-là...

Parfois ça ressemble à un mot d'encouragement, parfois à une forme de remontrance. À première vue on la dirait à mi-chemin entre « reprends-toi » et « reprends le dessus sur... », on se demande ce que ça veut dire au juste, incluant dans l'exemple, à **quel sens de [*reprendre*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/reprendre)** ça se rattache, est-ce *se ressaisir*, *se contrôler*, ou l'un et l'autre selon le contexte et y en a-t-il d'autres ; et **pourquoi la préposition *sur*** est-elle utile ici : pour indiquer une différence de sens de *reprends-toi* (à nouveau), pour évoquer « le dessus », pour mettre en valeur le pronom, par association avec l'emploi pronominal pour une raison que j'ignore... ? Finalement la trouve-t-on ailleurs dans la francophonie ?

Comment: C'est quoi un gros agrès?

Comment: @petitrien Avec l'objet, ce serait l'aspect stupéfiant ou étrange. Avec la personne, on dit que l'[_agrès_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/agr%C3%A8s#Nom_commun_2) c'est la personne désagréable ou négligée, mais c'est un terme plutôt [injurieux](https://www.laparlure.com/terme/agrais/). Le [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) parle aussi d'un « importun ». Les contextes d'emploi sont similaires à ceux d'« épais » (imbécile).

Comment: C'est une contraction phonétique de 'agressif'

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble plus simple de partir de « prendre sur soi » où l'emploi de « sur » est tout à fait clair et justifié.
« Prendre sur soi » c'est endosser quelque chose, en prendre le poids/la charge sur ses épaules/sur [son mental](https://www.psychologies.com/Bien-etre/Prevention/Hygiene-de-vie/Articles-et-Dossiers/Apaiser-ses-douleurs-en-agissant-sur-son-mental/7). Voir l'entrée *prendre sur soi* dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prendre) :

> Se retenir, se contraindre (d'agir de telle ou telle manière). *J'ai pris sur moi pour ne pas lui répondre*.

Dans la phrase que tu cites on pourrait très bien dire :

> Prends sur toi...

L'emploi de « reprendre sur » ici me suggère :

- soit un emploi abusif de **re**prendre à la place de prendre (à cause de la proximité lexicale ?) là où il n'y a pas de « reprise » (mais seulement une « prise » à faire),
- soit un glissement de l'emploi de la préposition d'une expression (« prendre sur soi ») à l'autre (« se reprendre »),
- soit une création langagière qui veut exprimer à la fois le fait de prendre sur soi et de **re**venir à un état antérieur.

Pour ce qui est de l'avoir entendu, personnellement je ne pense pas mais je ne suis pas la francophonie à moi seul, je ne représente pas non plus le français hexagonal dont je ne suis qu'un modeste locuteur et c'est le genre de question qui mérite une étude statistique approfondie pour y apporter une réponse.

Comment: Vu le contexte (cependant limité) j'aurais dit que le point de départ était plutôt "Se reprendre" que "Prendre sur soi". Belge de Belgique, je n'ai moi non plus jamais entendu "Reprendre sur soi" non plus.

Comment: Idem, "Reprends-toi" ou "Reprends sur toi", jamais entendu.
Par contre, pour la phrase qu'il cite, je vois mal le joueur dire à son gardien "Prends sur toi", ici c'est + la formule "Ressaisis-toi", "Réveille-toi", cadre sportif

Comment: @Kenichi-san Se reprendre :  « Réagir à quelque chose qui abat ou contrarie. Synon. se ressaisir; » [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/reprendre). « Retrouver la maîtrise de soi, se ressaisir » [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_reprendre/68476).

Comment: _Prendre sur soi_ possiblement une meilleure piste que _reprendre le dessus sur soi_ (!). La _proximité lexicale_, un terme à me rappeler. C'est très peu présent sur internet cette expression avec reprendre, mais je l'ai déjà entendue à l'oral.

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, je n’ai jamais entendu « reprends sur toi », mais plutôt reprends-toi qui est synonyme avec  recommence ou peut également faire référence à une reprise des sens.

Comment: Reprise des sens ou peut-être même... _reprendre ses esprits_...

Answer (score 0):

Je partage la perplexité des intervenants.  Je me demande s'il ne s'agit pas simplement d'une manière de dire  *Arrête les tirs, bloque la rondelle quand elle arrive sur le but*.  Le hockey est un jeu très rapide, souvent les gardiens ne stoppent le palet justement qu'en le prenant sur eux.

Comment: Original, mais non, je t'assure. En tapant l'expression entre guillemets sur un moteur tu vas voir des contextes probablement plus clairs, souvent l'encouragement dans la « relation d'aide », parfois même la personne se dit ça à elle-même. Ça peut être accompagné de trucs reliés à l'apaisement ou à la conduite personnelle, à la morale etc. Dans certains contextes ça pourrait être infantilisant ou [déplacé](http://publications.gc.ca/collections/collection_2013/dn-nd/D12-7-16-1-fra.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être que *se reprendre*, qu'on évoquait en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/reprends-sur-toi-en-langage-familier-du-qu%C3%A9bec-emploi-particulier-de-la-pr#comment75967_37890), est aussi une bonne piste ; tout comme la [référence](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/reprends-sur-toi-en-langage-familier-du-qu%C3%A9bec-emploi-particulier-de-la-pr#comment75973_37890) à « ressaisis-toi » et « réveille-toi ». Dans le [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) dont tu parles en commentaire, à *reprendre* t'as un sens en couture et l'autre pronominal, « prendre sa revanche, prendre le dessus, regagner l'avantage perdu. Ex.: Tu m'as battu mais je vais me *reprendre*. — Au commencement de la partie, il avait le dessous, mais il s'est *repris* à la fin. » (GPFC) ...en [*(re)prenant le dessus*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dessus/24680#178732) finalement... Donc dans certains cas (sport par exemple) ce pourrait être ces sens reliés à l'emploi pronominal et la préposition servirait à mettre l'accent sur le *dessus* ou à évoquer l'idée de [maîtrise de soi](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_reprendre/68476). J'ai bien peur que l'on soit revenu au point de départ mais on aura essayé !